# Librosa ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.ndimage'

Tags: python, module, librosa, anaconda3, scipy.ndimage

I am trying to use librosa library but whatever I do I take the following massage (Using Python 3.8 and PyCharm on Anaconda)

What I am trying:

```
import librosa
import IPython.display as ipd
sr = 22050 # sample rate
T = 5.0    # seconds
t = np.linspace(0, T, int(T*sr), endpoint=False) # time variable
x = 0.5*np.sin(2*np.pi*220*t)# pure sine wave at 220 Hz
#Playing the audio
ipd.Audio(x, rate=sr) # load a NumPy array
#Saving the audio
librosa.output.write_wav('tone_220.wav', x, sr)`
```

What I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Fall_2020/END/Yeni klasör/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import librosa
  File "C:\Users\UGURA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\librosa\__init__.py", line 211, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\UGURA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .convert import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "C:\Users\UGURA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\convert.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import notation
  File "C:\Users\UGURA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\notation.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ..util.exceptions import ParameterError
  File "C:\Users\UGURA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\librosa\util\__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from .utils import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "C:\Users\UGURA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\librosa\util\utils.py", line 6, in <module>
    import scipy.ndimage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.ndimage'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can somebody help me solve this? Should I uninstall librosa? I tried installing with conda and pip no results.

Answer (score 1):

[scipy.ndimage](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html) is part of the `scipy` package. Try `pip install scipy`.

Normally this would be automatically pulled in when you installed librosa. Why it did not in this case we cannot know without seeing the pip install logs.